# Need to install Xcode on OSX 10.7.2

Tags: xcode, installation

What version of Xcode should I use?
I tried installing 4.2 but got this cryptic error message
[image]

If i wasn't so annoyed I'd find this funny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason you're still on OS X 10.7.2? If you can, update your Mac to 10.7.4. As for Xcode, the current version is 4.3.2. You can download it from the Mac App Store.

Comment: Ummmm. 
1. how can I upgrade to 10.7.4                              ---2. I tried 4.3.2 and I didn't have 10.7.3 or greater.
I get the feeling that I need to upgrade, how?

Comment: Just go to the Apple Logo in the top left of your screen. Then hit Software Update and install 10.7.4.  I'm assuming you're running a version of 10.7 though.

Answer (score 1):

The latest stable Xcode release is 4.3.2 as of May 31st, 2012. I believe there was a version for Snow Leopard (10.6) that would not work with Lion (10.7). You'll need to be a member of the developer program (free, I believe) to [get the free download here](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/).

Answer (score 0):

I have osx 10.7.X and need to install Xcode. The late xcode 5.X versions which is available in app store is not compatible with the 10.7. Xcode4.5.1 cltools is compatible.

Older versions are difficult to locate and after quite a lot of search inside developer.apple.com located the Older versions of Xcode  [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?q=xcode)